# How to write td(Table data) in csv in single row after extracting Html Table?

Tags: python, selenium

I am Extracting Html table and writing in csv.But could not able to write in required format
webscraping: https://ipr.etsi.org/IPRDetails.aspx?IPRD_ID=2383&IPRD_TYPE_ID=2&MODE=2&sessionkey=53a715

[image]

As we have seen image there are three tables I have extracting using beautiful soup but can't able to write td in required format.The Required format is one time th(table heading) and td data in one row as shown in below screenshot

[image]

As we have seen first,Second and Third column every thing coming in single heading and third column under work item it is coming in comma separated  as shown in screenshot the result is required. I can't able to do.Below is the code

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
csvFile = open('Information.csv', 'wt+')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
html = urlopen('https://ipr.etsi.org/IPRDetails.aspx?IPRD_ID=2383&IPRD_TYPE_ID=2&MODE=2&sessionkey=53a715')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = bs.findAll('table')
for tr in table:
    rows = tr.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        csvRow = [] 
        for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
            csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
            print(csvRow)
        writer.writerow(csvRow)
```

Comment: This page can't be scrapped using Python Requests because at first some kind condition acceptance page is loaded and only if you accept it you move forward to the URL you are scraping. You need to use Selenium.

Comment: yes you  are right but only page i have to do and please run above program it works for me and only think i need is to write data in required format as shown